# How to create a program that runs my LUA code?

Tags: lua

So, hi!
I am very new to Coding outside of a Game-Creation Program that automatically creates executable files for me, and from Create Your Frisk and other projects, I know a decent chunk of the basics in LUA. but how do I make a program out of it?
Like, How do I make an executable?(I'm using visual studio to code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile your lua files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463198/compile-your-lua-files)

Comment: The program that runs your Lua program is the command line interpreter `lua`

Comment: Or the Interpreter that interprets ```lua``` is an Executable, in my Case: ```bash``` - And for the Operating System are special Libraries present that holding functions for it. The Point is: A Game gives Lua specialized functions (Keyboard, Mouse, Controller, Sound, Graphics, Physics, ...) you dont find in a pure Lua Environment specialized for the Operating System.

Comment: Example: Programm=Cherokee web server Technic: CGI - https://www.lua.org/demo.html - Its OS functions are limited (sandboxed) - Theres an unsupported Version of the CGI Scripts out there but i cant find it in the Moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Lua interpreter that runs your Lua code.

Either you use a standalone Lua interpreter, a little executable that can only run Lua scripts, or you embedd a Lua interpreter into your own application.

See http://www.lua.org/start.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the site!